obtain average from a data extracted from csv
I'm working with a csv file, I extract certain information given a condition, from it I have to obtain the average, but the result I obtain does not allow me to calculate the average, I tried converting it to integer and list but I am still in the same situation.
city=open('ciudades.csv')
lineas=csv.reader(city)
for a,name,countrycode,district, population in lineas:
    if countrycode =='AFG':
        print(population)
        a=[population]
        #a2=int(population)
        b=a.mean()
        print(b)
        #print(a2)

when I print population I obtain a str like this
1780000
237500
186800
127800


this is my csv file looks like and i want he average from the country code= AFG, so when i print my population y have this and i can't have the average from that list

What does your CSV file look like? What should you output look like?

How are you getting output at all? There is no list.mean function, so you should get an AttributeError.

Please make a [mre] including working code and input data as text, not a picture. Converting to int probably should have worked, so please show us that code specifically. And it seems like your filtering is working fine, so for the sake of example you might want to remove that code and just provide the filtered data.

This is an obvious application for Pandas. You can read in the CSV file, use 'groupby on the countrycode and directly calculated the mean City population for each country. Just 2 lines of code would give the information for every country.

There is no mean function on a list. You need to get these values in a list, then sum those values and divide by their length. A list comprehension will work nicely.
city = open('ciudades.csv')
lineas = csv.reader(city)

populations = [
  int(population)
  for a, name, countrycode, district, population in lineas
  if countrycode == 'AFG'
]

avg = sum(populations) / len(populations)

